# Is there a difference with the HTMLEditFormat function in ColdFusion CF9 versus CF10?

Tags: coldfusion, escaping, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I'm seeing a difference in how HTMLEditFormat works in CF9 and CF10.

```
HTMLEditFormat("&gt;")
```

- In CF9: showing up as "&gt;" (no difference)
- In CF10: showing up as "&amp;gt;" (double-escaped, which seems correct to me)

I've looked through the [CF10 notes](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/release-note/coldfusion-10-release-notes.html) and reviewed the [HTMLEditFormat documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/HTMLEditFormat), but cannot find any mention of there being a difference in how this function works. Does anyone know of a difference, or know of documentation that proves there is no difference? ...Or know of any other settings (ColdFusion or web server) that might cause this to work different?

(This question is not a duplicate because am not asking about `encodeForHTML`. I understand that is the ideal solution, but am asking to understand why `HTMLEditFormat` might be different in CF9 vs. CF10.)

Comment: sorry about marking it as duplicated earlier, I'd file this as a bug for CF9 at : bugbase.adobe.com but I doubt Adobe will bother fixing anything for CF9.  They will just ask you to upgrade the latest CF.

Comment: Are you looking at the HTML source that is generated to verify the values? I tested on ColdFusion 9 and it works as documented; `< = &lt;` and `> = &gt;` and `& = &amp;` and `" = &quot;` and finally `&gt; = &amp;gt;`.

Comment: Yes, I am. To clarify: when I say "showing up as" I mean in the source HTML, not the rendered webpage. Thanks for trying this out. The two servers I'm testing on have the same code but are not 100% the same (aside from CF versions), so there could be something else that is un-escaping the text on the server-side. I just don't know what it could be. So I guess the second question I have is the real one: "Know of any other settings (ColdFusion or web server) that might cause this to work different?"

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine why that function would behave differently. Especially when it's was planned for deprecation going into CF 10. By chance, are you calling it from within a `CFINPUT` tag?

`<cfinput id="foo" value="#htmlEditFormat(someValue)#" />`

If so, in CF6 - CF9, that tag uses `HTMLEditFormat()` on values automatically. Calling a 2nd instance of `HTMLEditFormat()` doesn't affect the output. But CF 10+ updated the tag to use `encodeForHTML()` on values. If you also throw in an `HTMLEditFormat()`, then you're double-encoding the output.

For better security, you should stop using `HTMLEditFormat()` and start using `encodeForHTML()` if it's available (CF10+). As of ColdFusion 11, `HTMLEditFormat()` has been officially deprecated and by ColdFusion 12, the function should be removed completely.

`HTMLEditFormat()` only encodes 4 characters: `<, >, &, "`.

`encodeForHTML()` encodes almost every character, including UTF-8 characters. The updated "encodeFor" functions are contextual, so you have to pick the right on for the right context (html, htmlattribute, js, css, xml, etc.).

Comment: I'm not using cfinput, I've just isolated the problem so all I'm doing is basically `writeOutput(HTMLEditFormat(escapedCharacters));` Unfortunately we can't take advantage of CF10's `encodeForHTML()` function, although I know that would be the best solution!

Comment: Just a minor point: just because HTMLEditFormat() is now deprecated doesn't mean it will be removed any time soon (like in CF12).  There's a bunch of stuff that was deprecated as far back as CF6 that either is still hanging around or was just finally removed in CF11.

Comment: Yes, but the CF team has already stated that CF 12 WILL break backward compatibility by removing certain deprecated functions like HTMLEditFormat(). http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/10/cfsummit-interesting-coldfusion-12-stuff.html